# mvc without view - controller connection

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I know how classic MVC looks like, but I was asked to write game using other type of MVC. I mean something like this : [Draw which show my lecturer](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/mvcs.jpg/)

BQ is LinkedBlockingQueue of Events. And I don't know how in this situation model can tell view and controller that his state has changed? My antoher problem with this MVCis fact that Controller shoud make deccision about consequenses of Clicked Button, but again, there is no connection from view to controller. Is it means that View should implement ActionListers inside of it?

Comment: What do you mean by another type of MVC? It makes sense to make a listener on view, but you should handle the (game) logic in your controller.

Comment: Game logic in controller, not in model? Another type of MVC - this what shows picture in link (i have less than 10 rep so I had to put it on imagineshack).

Comment: You should not handle your game logic in model(most of the times). Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the diagram shows the view generating events and placing them on a queue. The controller is reading from the queue and updating the model/notifying the view accordingly. To me this is still MVC.

Comment: Hym... I still don't get it, because he also said something like "the idea of this is view hanging on bq, and it's notifying only when controller pass something to do in bq.". And I still don't know how about communication between model and controller. There is only one arrow - from controller to model. Imo there have to be arrow from model to controller.

Comment: According to the diagram provided, the arrows tell you who knows about who. So the view has a reference to the BQ and can place events on it. The controller has a reference to the BQ and can read from it. It also has references to the model and view to update them. The model doesn't know about the controller or view, as it does not act on them.

Comment: So after every model update I have to check if its state didn't change ?